# Securing edit and delete of records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have used annotations to stop unauthorised user accessing data but now face the problem of stopping authenticated users editing and deleting each other’s records.
If this was typed in by an logged on user localhost/User/Edit/43  - the record could be changed!  Even thou the record does not belong to the logged on  user.

This is what I used for this query to only allow the logged on user to view their own records.

```
 var Adverts = from b in db.Adverts
                        .Where(c => c.Customer.Username == User.Identity.Name)
                                         select b;
```

Having difficult trying to implement edit and delete security for users.
Any advice will be most welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did above is correct, but you should also try this load for edit and delete before you actually apply the changes. This way you can check if not records are returned and return a 404 (not found as opposed to unauthorized) as these are data loading rules at this point. The same type of logic applies in any multi-tenant application where you only load the data based on the user id, company id, etc

You'll quickly realize how many of your tables will require user ids, company ids, etc.

Comment: I have been at this for a long while any more information would be helpful

Comment: I have tried using it in the edit and delete with an if statement but find it difficult to implement; not sure how to go about it!

Comment: in your edit method, load your record from the db. Include in the load the criteria 'where userid=@yourUsersID' . If this returns null, then you know the record doesn't exist so either someone deleted it or they don't have access, either way return a 404 (or exception depending on how you want to handle this) . If the record returns from the database, then assign the properties from the posted model into the object you loaded from the database. Save the database object and you are done.  This is the same for delete. In an HttpPost Delete method,

Comment: read the id they want to delete. Load the  record from the database based on the passed in ID AND the user's id to ensure they have access. If no record is returned, handle that case with a 404 or exception.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could change the way your users navigate to their records.  At the moment you are allowing them to get to each other's records via the URL (with a GET).  You could lock this down a bit more by only allowing them access via a POST (form submission).  If your data is particularly sensitive I would strongly recommend you make this change.

But, either way, if the data is sensitive you should then check they do have permission to change the thing they are trying to change.  This isn't provided by the framework - you need to code it.  I would check who owns the record before you show the page and send back a 401 if they have tried to circumvent your security.  But you might decide to do this when they try and POST the change because you might be happy that they see it.

I hope this helps.